# WebService for Elmah

Tags: elmah

We are looking to implement a web service for Elmah that our web services and some console apps can utilize. Is there a service out there that has already tested and is preferred?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the purpose of the webservice?

Comment: For getting the errors from desktop executables. We also have some .net exe that are called by windows services and for when they throw errors.

Comment: I don't believe that there's a web service available for ELMAH. But if the hosts running your services can reach the ELMAH store, you can use ELMAHs ErrorLog class as a .NET client.